# PowerDNS-Recursor transmits the client’s IP (and not its)

Tags: dns, bind, powerdns

I am writing to you because I built an infrastructure with a Bind server and a PowerDNS recursor that transmits the requests to the Bind server. What I wanted to do was that the recursor transmits the ip of the client and not its., so I tried to do that using EDNS(0).
Here is a diagram that summarizes what I want to do:

```
Client : 10.0.0.1/24
|
| “test.com”
|
Server with PDNS-RECURSOR : 192.168.1.1/24
|
| “test.com”  with ip_source=10.0.0.1/24
|
Server with BIND : 192.168.1.2/24
```

And the different configurations files :

•   BIND Conf :  3 views

```
View recursor {} #Return specific IP for the recursor machine
View localhost {} #Return specific IP for the localhost machine.
View external {} #Return specific IP for the external machines.
```

•   Pdns-Recursor Conf (4.1):

```
edns-outgoing-bufsize=1680
edns-subnet-whitelist=0.0.0.0/0.
forward-zones=192.168.1.2
use-incoming-edns-subnet=yes
```

Unfortunately, it always returns the view of the recursor, do you have a solution?
Thank you in advance !

Answer (score 1):

You can not transmit the IP but you can transmit a subnet. This needs an EDNS option called Client-Subnet, described in [RFC7871](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc7871)

For PowerDNS this is controlled in configuration by various options starting with `ecs-`, see https://doc.powerdns.com/recursor/settings.html#ecs-add-for

You may try `ecs-ipv4-bits: 32` to try sending the whole IP (the option was more about sending a subnet, for privacy issues).

Bind configuration regarding this option is described at https://www.isc.org/wp-content/uploads/2017/04/ecs.pages.pdf

You should sniff out the traffic between the two to make sure PowerDNS sends correctly the information to bind.

You can also try with `dig` querying directly bind with the appropriate client subnet option (`+subnet=`) to make sure bind does what you need.